# Toolbar shows no icons

Tags: winapi, mfc, mfc-feature-pack, cmfctoolbar

I have been trying to put a CMFCMenuBar and CMFCToolBar together. The OnCreate of CFrameWndEx has following code for the purpose

```
if ( !m_wndMenuBar.Create(this) ) {
    TRACE0("Failed to create menubar\n");
    return -1;      // fail to create
}
m_wndMenuBar.SetPaneStyle( m_wndMenuBar.GetPaneStyle() | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY );
CMFCPopupMenu::SetForceMenuFocus(FALSE);
CList<UINT, UINT>   lstBasicCommands;

lstBasicCommands.AddTail (ID_FILE_NEW);
lstBasicCommands.AddTail (ID_FILE_OPEN);
lstBasicCommands.AddTail (ID_FILE_SAVE);
lstBasicCommands.AddTail (ID_APP_EXIT);
lstBasicCommands.AddTail (ID_APP_ABOUT);

CMFCToolBar::SetBasicCommands (lstBasicCommands);

CMFCToolBarInfo toolBarStruct;
SecureZeroMemory( &toolBarStruct, sizeof(CMFCToolBarInfo) );
toolBarStruct.m_uiMenuResID = IDR_TOOLBAR;
m_wndToolBar.SetMenuSizes( CSize(21,22), CSize(15,16) );
if (!m_wndToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC ) ||//, CRect(1,1,1,1), theApp.m_bHiColorIcons ? IDR_TOOLBAR_MAIN_256 : IDR_TOOLBAR_MAIN ) ||
    !m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBarEx(IDR_TOOLBAR, toolBarStruct) ) {
    TRACE0("Failed to create toolbar\n");
    return -1;
}

m_wndMenuBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
DockPane(&m_wndMenuBar, CBRS_ALIGN_TOP);
DockPane(&m_wndToolBar);
```

The resultant UI that shows is something like

[image: Resultant UI]

My question is two fold.
1. Why isnt the toolbar showing any icons?
2. Why isnt the menubar taking up the whole avaiable space horizontally?

Comment: What do you have in IDR_TOOLBAR resource?

Comment: Please, only one question per post. You could remove the second question altogether, because it has such a trivial answer (*"Why isnt the menubar taking up the whole avaiable space horizontally?"* - *"Because it's implemented not to spread across the entire available horizontal space."*).

Comment: In Customize mode (Right-click menu bar  > Customize), try to drag some menu items of menu bar menus and see what happens. **ATTENTION:**  Press `Ctrl` key while dragging using the mouse. If you don't, application will **move** the item instead of **copy**, and the menu will not be any more where it was